# AngularJs doesn't render data changed on service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service `MediaService` and i change its data inside a component.
`MediaService` data are bind to another component, and when i change data from first component it doesn't render on second component HTML.

**MediaService**

```
angular
.module('commons')
.service('MediaService', function () {

    this.selectedMedia = {}
    this.isPlaying = false

    return this;

})
```

This is where i change data

**readerMedias**

```
angular
.module("app")
.component("readerMedias", {
    bindings: {
        medias: "="
    },
    templateUrl: "app/reader/components/reader-medias/reader-medias.html",
    controller: function (MediaService) {
        MediaService.selectedMedia.url = "test" // i use a real url
        MediaService.selectedMedia.type = "video" 
        MediaService.isPlaying = true
    }
})
```

This is the component where i want the changes, and as i can debug data are reflected here and it is ok, but not in component HTML

**readerPlayer**

```
angular
.module('app')
.component('readerPlayer', {
    templateUrl: 'app/reader/components/reader-player/reader-player.html',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    controller: function (MediaService, $scope){
        $scope.MediaService = MediaService
        console.log(MediaService)
        return this;
    }
})
```

**readerPlayer HTML**

```
div.playing-media(
    ng-draggable
    ng-init="$ctrl.isFull = true"
    ng-class="{\
        'full-media': $ctrl.isFull, \
        'min-media': !$ctrl.isFull \
    }"
    ng-if="MediaService.isPlaying"
)
    div.playing-head
        div
            span.material-icons.full(
                ng-click="$ctrl.isFull = !$ctrl.isFull"
            ) photo_size_select_large
        span.material-icons.close(
            ng-click="MediaService.isPlaying = false"
        ) clear

    div.content
        video(
            controls
            ng-if="MediaService.selectedMedia.type != audio"
        )
            source(
                ng-src="{{MediaService.selectedMedia.url}}"
                type="video/mp4"
            )

        audio(
            ng-if="MediaService.selectedMedia.type == audio"
        )
            source(
                ng-src="{{MediaService.selectedMedia.url}}"
                type="audio/mp3"
            )
```

Comment: You did not attach the HTML template.

Comment: @OlivierLiechti thanks, i did change it now

Comment: In your controller you assign a string to `MediaService.selectedMedia` but then in your template you treat it as if it's an object. Where does that object come from?

Comment: In your service, you don't return anything. And then you don't make any call to the service (obviously).

Comment: @JCFord my bad when i writed the question, now i edited the question.

Comment: @OlivierLiechti that is not the problem because it is EcmaScript and it return this, i can access my service variables and i can use them in both components the only problem is with HTML rendering

Comment: @OlivierLiechti it's being registered with the `.service()` method, not the `.factory()` method. Doesn't have to return anything. Just serves as a constructor.

Comment: @MarjoBallabani So you set the `MediaService` values in the readerMedias constructor? Not in an event callback?

Comment: @OlivierLiechti as i mentioned, Everything is ok with service i can access data in both components and is the same at both components so when i change to one component it reflect other component, the problem is rendering to HTML. First render is done and when i update the value of selectedMedia it doesnt reflect on HTML

Comment: @JCFord yes you are right

Comment: What are you using to compile the template to HTML? Just Jade? Can you verify the output HTML is what you expect?

Comment: @JCFord i use pug, and to compile i use gulp. It is a large project and dev tools are perfect, html is as i expect

Comment: I'm still not clear on how the properties of MediaService change. You're setting them in the constructor of readerMedias controller, but that only executes once when the readerMedias component is rendered. When do those properties change?

Comment: @JCFord readerMedias has a function that does what i did on its controller and change it with dynamic data, i puted it this way for simplicity

Comment: What calls that function? An event? What is its source?

Comment: I ask because if it comes from outside the angular domain, such as a jQuery event, then angular will not know to trigger a digest cycle and you'll have to do it yourself with `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: @JCFord it is a simple function without async or stuff like this this.play(url){ MediaService.url = url }

Comment: @JCFord yes i know that but it is just siple function, as i mentioned before changes are done they are reflected on service and on the other component, it doesnt rerender data on update

Comment: That is exactly the sort of behavior one would see if it were a digest cycle issue. How is the function called? Is it an event handler for a UI component? Is it a timer? We'll need more details and/or more code to help.

Comment: @JCFord button(ng-click= $ctrl.play())

Answer (score 1):

Delete the [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement in the service:

```
angular
.module('commons')
.service('MediaService', function () {

    this.selectedMedia = {}
    this.isPlaying = false

    //DELETE the return statement    
    ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶

    //OR

    return this;    
})
```

Without a `return` statement, the constructor automatically returns the `this` object created by the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

---

The string needs quotes:

```
div.content
    video(
        controls
        ng-if="MediaService.selectedMedia.type !=  ̶a̶u̶d̶i̶o̶  ͟'͟a͟u͟d͟i͟o͟'͟ "
    )
        source(
            ng-src="{{MediaService.selectedMedia.url}}"
            type="video/mp4"
        )

    audio(
        ng-if="MediaService.selectedMedia.type ==   ̶a̶u̶d̶i̶o̶  ͟'͟a͟u͟d͟i͟o͟'͟ "
    )
        source(
            ng-src="{{MediaService.selectedMedia.url}}"
            type="audio/mp3"
        )
```

Without quotes the media type is being compared to `$scope.audio` which is undefined.

Comment: I tryed this before no effect at all